# Molecular simulation applied to astrobiology

Tags: simulations, biophysics, molecular-dynamics, chemical-compounds

There is some research group which use molecular dynamics simulations to study the origin of life according to the hypothesis of abiogenesis?

I'm just beginning to know this subject so I don't know about its applicability in certain problems, but I wonder if molecular simulations plays the main role in any area of astrobiology.

(I'm not so sure about asking this question here instead Astronomy or Space Exploration sites, but sounds like a physics question to me.)

Comment: Honestly, astrobiology is just hypothetical/theoretical [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/). Organic molecules and cell membranes function the same no matter where they are in the universe, and it's not like astronomers or rocket engineers are simulating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Molecular simulation is certainly used in the field of astrobiology. For example, here's a quote from a [NASA technical report](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=20010095454) specifically on Molecular Simulations in Astrobiology:

> We use computer simulations to address the following, questions about
>   these proteins: (1) How do small proteins (peptides) organize
>   themselves into ordered structures at water-membrane interfaces and
>   insert into membranes? (2) How do peptides aggregate to form
>   membrane-spannin(y structures (e.g., channels)? (3) By what mechanisms
>   do such aggregates perform their functions? The simulations are
>   performed using the molecular dynamics (MD) method

However, molecular simulation is greatly limited in the size and time-scales that it can currently access, it is also unable to model chemical processes like bond breaking (unless you introduce ad hoc modifications or couple it with very expensive quantum mechanical methods) and so studies are generally restricted to solving these very specific problems (like studying structures or computing energies) for specific molecules, rather than the broad and vague problem of abiogenesis.

Nevertheless, this [PhD thesis](http://www.damer.com/writings/doctoral/Damer-Bruce-Phd-thesis-COMPRESSED-FINAL.pdf) seems to be a serious first-attempt in that direction (although I've only skimmed through it so cannot vouch for its quality).

Comment: Your answer killed many birds with one stone, mainly the quote from report, it gave me some ideas of what to search for, thank you!